# What does custom app notification means in my notifications history?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger

Whenever I check my notifications history for Whatsapp on my android phone’s Notification history, a few of my notification’s history states “custom app notification”. What does this mean?

The messages are not there. Does any one deletes messages on my phone?

Also when i open the custom app notification and filter it for "Whatsapp", in my notification history it says “media playback”

I am attaching screenshots for reference:

[image: notification history]

My phone is Samsung S23 ultra

Comment: On plain Android there is only the [notification history of all apps in Android settings](https://www.androidpolice.com/check-android-notification-history-guide/). Your history looks different therefore I agree with Andrew that the shown screen may belong to a manufacturer modification. Please tell use your phone manufacturer and model name and how you have reached the screen shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

First the notification history shows you every notification of every app on your Andrid phone, not only Whatsapp messages.

Thus not every notification is a Whatsapp "message". Every app can send you notifications.

Even a notification of Whatsapp does not mean there was a message. In most apps that play audio/video, when you play a media file a notification will be shown that allows to play/pause/stop the playback even if the app is background. My guess is that this custom "media playback" app notification is such a notification, when playing an audio/video file in Whatsapp itself or from a different app.

Comment: So the phone model is s23 ultra and the android version I can’t find. 
I go to settings > notifications history > WhatsApp. And there is shows the “ custom app notification”.

Comment: Robert i agree that this notification is from an audio or video file in whatsapp. But the notification history actually shows the sender name in case of and audio or video message, but here it only says custom app notification

Comment: I went into the samsung settings, then i got to the notification, then to advance settings, then into notifications history, then i drop down Whatsapp from there and it shows the custom app notification there. Its basically the same notification history but instead of showing a message or atleast it should say a voice message. It says custom app notification

Comment: did you get what you wanted to know from my side? Or do you need more info?

Comment: @AliHashmi Sorry I can not add any thing to my answer. My Samsung tablet running Android 14 does not have a notification history filtering feature. So my answer stays, these notifications most likely do not belong to messages.

Comment: Robert the android version is 14. Phone manufacturer is Samsung, the model is Samsung S23 Ultra. I think in android 14 there is a feature. We go to settings> notifications tab> advance settings tab> notifications history> then scroll down to where we see WhatsApp. Under Whatsapp tab, i can see every notification or message that I receive, however some notifications say “custom app notification”. I do not understand that